# Azure Stream Analytics suddenly getting huge increase in input events

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

We suddenly experience a huge increase in the number of input events from one particular input in Stream Analytics. Nothing has been changed in the Stream Analytics job at all in connection with the increase. The Azure Function that produces messages to the Event Hub that acts as input was deployed with a minor change just around the time of the increase. Looking at the Event Hub metrics, though, shows that the number of incoming messages has not increased since the deploy, but the number of outgoing messages has increased in accordance to the increase in input events to Stream Analytics.

Also, the number of input events keep increasing, it has not stabilized:

[image]

Our basic flow is this:

Azure Function -> Event Hub -> Stream Analytics -> SQL Server

The increase in number of input events causes performance issues and a significant delay in output events from Stream Analytics, so it's a serious issue. Stopping and starting the Stream Analytics job causes the output to catch up temporarily but then the problem starts building again.

So to summarize:

- The Stream Analytics job has not been changed in any way
- There has not been a corresponding increase in the number of output events
- There are no runtime errors in Stream Analytics
- The number of incoming messages to the connected Event Hub has *not* increased
- Rolling back the Azure Function to a previous commit does not solve the issue
- Restarting the Stream Analytics job temporarily lets the output catch up but then the problem starts building again, the number of input events go back to the same high level

Anyone got any clue what could have happened?

Edit:

The resource utilization of the Stream Analytics job has increased accordingly but not by many percentage points:

[image]

The Event Hub metrics clearly show that the outgoing messages started vastly outgrow the incoming messages at the same time the Stream Analytics input events started increasing, and that turning off the Stream Analytics job stops the outgoing messages:

[image]

Comment: Hi Hannes. This is too specific of an issue to be discussed here. You will need to open a support ticket in the Azure Portal so we can have a look at your specific telemetry.

Comment: @FlorianEiden Unfortunately I don't have a mandate to upgrade our support plan to the necessary level. So that is not an option.

Comment: From your description I'm not sure if it's the increase in number of events that is the issue (unexpected, and doesn't show on EH telemetry), or the scaling issues of the job (not being able to process that new workload timely). Could you also share your resource utilization metrics?

Comment: @FlorianEiden Sure, I've updated the description. The increase in input events is totally unexpected and unexplained, though. As said, the number of incoming EH messages has not increased but you can see in the EH metrics that the outgoing messages have indeed increased.

Comment: Ok, so after creating a completely new Event Hub and routing the messages there instead, and adding that as an input and switching out the old input in the Stream Analytics query, it all starts behaving as expected again. But it doesn't explain the original issue, at all.

Comment: When deploying the Azure Function that produces the messages with _zero code changes_ the behaviour starts all over again. I am completely dumbfounded at the moment.